# Cannot Fetch a Data From Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

First of all i'm new to Android Development.
I'm having some issues with fetching data from database. Whenever i try to fetch a data, the cursor is being empty.

Here is my code:

```
public ArrayList<Word> getWords(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<Word> List = new ArrayList<Word>();

    if(cursor != null){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            List.add(new Word(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition())));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return List;
}
```

The size of the cursor is always 1 but the size of the "List" variable is always 0.

I didn't understand the problem, thanks for helping me.

Comment: maybe you need to put to the end ";" of query ("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + ";"). If you need all rows use: Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like a idiot because i forgot to type the database name at the constructor method like that:

**Old**

```
super(context, null, null, 1);
```

**Now**

```
super(context, "database", null, 1);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You are shifting the cursor position twice. Just remove the line **cursor.moveToFirst();** The **moveToNext** method is sufficient as it moves to the first position on the first iteration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is more readable if formatted as such.  Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.  I do give you credit for making the code in bold in your current answer.

Comment: Thanks @Gary99, I will have a look at the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

1-If you need first row:

```
if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
        List.add(new Word(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition())));
        }
}
```

2- if you need several rows :

```
if(cursor != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();            
        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        List.add(new Word(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition())));
        cursor.moveToNext();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I  checked everything but your recommendations didn't worked. Just to be sure: I want to fetch all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
public ArrayList<Word> getWords(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<Word> list = new ArrayList<Word>();

    if(cursor != null){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            list.add(new Word(cursor.getString(cursor.getPosition())));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realised that the program does not go into the while loop in the code that i given above. I think there is a problem with database.

I used that query to create database:

```
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_TURKISH + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_ENGLISH + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_GERMAN + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_FRENCH + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_ARABIC + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_RUSSIAN + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_SPANISH + " TEXT, " +
                    COLUMN_NAME_ITALIAN + " TEXT)";
```